# How to install PyPlot in Julia into a folder defined by me?

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia, julia-plots

My real name and therefore my user folder contains special characters. When installing PyPlot in Julia using the `] add PyPlot` command, it has a problem with the special characters, because it wants to install it into `C:\Users\Janko Hraško\.julia`. Then later in the installation it has problems with the special characters. How do i specify where do i want to install the PyPlot (for instance directly do C:), so there are no special characters in the way?

Comment: Could you post some more details about what the error is, and if possible the entire stacktrace?  It would be helpful to narrow down whether the issue is directly with Julia, or with the Python code which is required to build PyPlot.jl.